# 'Beautiful arrays' CodeChef, how to input data

Tags: python, arrays, input

Here's the problem statement:

> An array a is called beautiful if for every pair of numbers ai, aj, (i
> ≠ j), there exists an ak such that ak = ai * aj. Note that k can be
> equal to i or j too.
>
> Find out whether the given array a is beautiful or not!
>
> Input
>
> First line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number of
> test cases. T test cases follow.
>
> First line of each test case contains an integer n denoting number of
> elements in a.
>
> Next line contains n space separated integers denoting the array a.
> Output
>
> For each test case, output a single line containing "yes" or "no"
> (without quotes) corresponding to the answer of the problem.
> Constraints
>
> ```
> 1 ≤ T ≤ 106
> 1 ≤ n ≤ 105
> Sum of n over all the test cases ≤ 106
> -109 ≤ ai ≤ 109
> ```
>
> Example
>
> Input
>
> 3
>
> 2
>
> 0 1
>
> 2
>
> 1 2
>
> 2
>
> 5 6
>
> Output:
>
> yes
>
> yes
>
> no

I am new to CodeChef and can't work out how to correctly take in an input, I have some code that I am trying to use to solve the beautiful arrays problem but when I run it I get a NZEC.

```
from collections import Counter
numCase = int(input())
for i in range(numCase):
    length = input()
    array = Counter(input().split(''))
    answer = "no"
    for i in range(length - 1):
        if array[i] == 0 or array[i] == 1:
            answer = "yes"

    print(answer)
```

When I change the inputs and manually input some data the code works for me, can anybody tell me why this code doesn't work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not checking the last element of array because of range. try this

```
for i in range(length)
```

Comment: I still get the same error after this, although this was an error with my code the NZEC error seems to mean Non Zero Exit Code, but Im not sure what this points to I'm my code

Comment: Can you give me the link to question you're attempting because maybe I'm misunderstanding your question and logic.

Comment: But for this question I guess your logic is incomplete. Think about array {2, 3, 6} it has the pair(ai and aj) which results to ak(6) but according to your logic it would result false but it is true. Right?

Comment: Yeah I understand that but this was just sort of a test to work out how to take inputs from the site, unless additional test data is being used on the code then I'm still unsure why it doesn't work, but I will try it with a more complete solution.

Comment: @MohammadNadeem If you have array a={2, 3, 6}, the solution should be "no". a[k] must exist for ALL pairs according to the problem statement. For example, a[1] * a[2] == 18 (i.e. 3 * 6 == 18), but 18 is not in a.

Answer (score 0):

First, your code as-is *crashes* when you run it by hand. Minimally you need to change `length = input()` to `length = int(input())`. The NZEC is a runtime error, which is CodeChef telling you that your code is crashing.

Second, it's best not to reference external sites. Give your potential answerers a fighting chance and give us the problem. It's not convenient to look up CodeChef, what it is, and where I can find the problem statement. Additionally, CodeChef might go away, or might be down, and then you obviously can't get an answer. That being said, I've put the problem statement in your question.

Lastly, your solution is fundamentally flawed in terms of logic (not just crashing). It does not suffice to check whether the first two items in the array are `0` and `1` respectively. You are sort of close to having an efficient solution, though. Observe the following input/output:

```
1

3

1 -4 -1

# Output should be "no", since -4 * -1 == 4, and 4 is not in the list.
```

Also, consider

```
1

5

0 1 2 3 4 5

# Output should be "no" since 2 * 3 == 6, but 6 is not in the list
```

The base case (if the array len == 1) is a "yes" output. This is not correct in my opinion (i cannot equal j, pairs are not well defined for input of length one, I could go on...). So I'm willing to give you that part of the solution since it fooled me too and it's not particularly clear.

As a side note, it seems that I've seen some misinterpretations of the problem on this thread, so I'll try to add some clarification.

> An array a is called beautiful if for every pair of numbers ai, aj, (i
>   ≠ j), there exists an ak such that ak = ai * aj. Note that k can be
>   equal to i or j too.

The important words here are "*for **every** pair of numbers ai, aj there exists ak*", not just *some* pair. This means that if we have input array `[2, 3, 6]`, the answer is "no", because 3 * 6 == 18, but 18 is not in the array. It's tempting to think that the answer should be "yes" because 2 * 3 == 6, but that's just *some* pair that satisfies the relation. The question makes it clear that *every* pair must satisfy the relation.

Here's my solution. I was tempted not to post it, but if you *really* get stuck, this can be your reference. I strongly suggest you do not look at the solution right away, give yourself at least a full day to solve it, and be sure to sleep on it. You won't learn anything by copy/pasting my solution into CodeChef. Hover over the section below to see my solution.

> ```
> numCase = int(input())
> for i in range(numCase):
>     length = int(input())
>     array = [int(x) for x in input().split(' ')]
>     num_neg_ones = len([x for x in array if x == -1])
>     num_ones = len([x for x in array if x == 1])
>     num_other = len([x for x in array if x not in [0, -1, 1]])
>
>     answer = "yes"
>     if num_other > 1:
>         answer = "no"
>     if num_other == 1 and num_neg_ones > 0:
>         answer = "no"
>     if num_neg_ones > 1 and num_ones == 0:
>         answer = "no"
>     print(answer)
> ```